# How to get object of array in view file in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working with ionic framework I am getting data into localStorage.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function(Auth,$scope,$http, $ionicModal,$location,$state,$window,$localStorage, $sessionStorage,$timeout,$ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    //$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function () { $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true) });
    $scope.adminData = $localStorage.adminData;
    $scope.forgetData = $sessionStorage.forgetData;
    $scope.levels = $localStorage.levels;

    $scope.loginData = {}
        // Create the login modal that we will use later
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });
        $scope.levels = function() {
            $http({
                url: 'http://localhost/bearscoaching/api/classes',
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
                })
            .then(function successCallback(response) 
            {
                function isObjectHasData(object)
                { 

                  return (object != null && typeof object != 'undefined' && Object.keys(object).length > 0);
                }
                if(isObjectHasData(response.data))
                {
                    $scope.dp = response.data;
                    $localStorage.levels =  $scope.dp;


                    /*angular.forEach($localStorage.levels, function(user, arrayID) 
                    {
                        alert(user.name);
                    });*/
                    $state.go('app.search');
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert("Data is not available");
            //$state.go('app.dashboard');

        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) 
    {
        console.log(response);
        // $state.go('app.dashboard');

        alert("Data is not available");
    });
        };

    })
```

when I run foreach loop I am  getting every name in alert.But when I get these data in view file like:

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-view  view-title="Marie Simpson" id="mainpage" hide-nav-bar="false">
        <ion-content padding="true" scroll="false">

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="item in levels">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>  
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</ion-modal-view>
```

I am not getting name of list.my response is

```
ngStorage-levels: "[{"id":2,"name":"Level I"},{"id":3,"name":"Level I…":6,"name":"Level V"},{"id":7,"name":"Level VI"}]"
```

Comment: As localStorage data seems to be stringfied, you have to parse it to json before using it like `$scope.levels = JSON.parse($localStorage.levels);`

Comment: @PankajParkar if I use your solution I am getting error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Try this: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name".toString()))